# Spin problem in ur_10 class

Tags: ros, msg-subscriber, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a class `position.cpp` where I manipulate my robot ur_10 and in this class I must to launch
`spinner.start()`
In this class I would to subscribe to a topic, and for doing this and I wrote this class:

```
class ListMsg {
private:
    ros::Subscriber sub;
    ros::NodeHandle n;
public:
ListMsg(){
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe ("chatter", 500, &Subscribe_And_Publish::callback, this);
  ros::spin();
}

void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

};
```

From my `position.cpp` I call this class in this way:

```
ListMsg listMsg1;
```

The problem is that my class doesn't print any information. How can I resolve it?

Thank you all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282628/spin-problem-in-ur_10-class/) by [Dalde](https://answers.ros.org/users/33236/dalde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How can I resolve it?

Don't call `ros::spin()` in your constructor.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0